# Sorting a Dictionary and writing it to a CSV file

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a dictionary with a tuple as a key and list as values

```
myDict = {
 (1, 9078752378): [('Smith', 'Bob'), 'Head guard'],
 (2, 9097615707): [('Burdell', 'George'), 'Lifeguard'],
 (3, 9048501430): [('Smith', 'Amanda'), 'Lifeguard'],
 (4, 9026450912): [('Brown', 'John'), 'Lifeguard'],
 (5, 9027603006): [('Flowers', 'Claudia'), 'Lifeguard'],
 (6, 9055520890): [('Smith', 'Brown'), 'Head guard'],
 (7, 9008197785): [('Rice', 'Sarah'), 'Lifeguard'],
 (8, 9063479070): [('Dodd', 'Alex'), 'New Lifeguard'],
 (9, 9072301498): [('Sparrow', 'Jack'), 'New Lifeguard'],
 (10, 9084389677): [('Windsor', 'Harry'), 'New Lifeguard']
}
```

I am COMPLETELY stuck on how to write this dictionary to a csv file in order 
written in this format

```
1 9078752378 Smith Bob Head guard
```

..and so on to 9

PLEASE HELP!!!

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your format is consistent, this should do the trick:

```
with open('youfile.csv', 'w') as f:
  for k,v in sorted(myDict.iteritems()):
    f.write('{} {} {} {} {}\n'.format(k[0], k[1], v[0][0], v[0][1], v[1]))
```

I should warn you about a potential gotcha in your output format though, if you need to parse this back again you want to quote values, or use a different separator, e.g.:

`1 9078752378 Smith Bob "Head guard"`

Comment: This worked but in the excel format it was placed in one cell how would i place each row entry in separate cells

Comment: Try using `'{},{},{},{},{}\n'` instead of `'{} {} {} {} {}\n'`

Comment: And be sure to check out the [CSV](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module.

Answer (score 3):

```
with open("CSV", 'w') as f:
   f.write('\n'.join([",".join(map(str,[a,b,c,d,e])) for (a, b), ((c, d), e) in sorted(myDict.items())]))
```

Explanation -

`sorted(myDict.items())` will sort the the dictionary based on keys.

`for (a, b), ((c, d), e) in sorted(myDict.items())` will unpack your values.

`",".join(map(str,[a,b,c,d,e]))` will join the unpacked values by comma.

`[",".join(map(str,[a,b,c,d,e])) for (a, b), ((c, d), e) in sorted(myDict.items())]` is the list comprehension of the above comma-joined values.

`'\n'.join([",".join(map(str,[a,b,c,d,e])) for (a, b), ((c, d), e) in sorted(myDict.items())]` will join the above list with newlines.

Comment: Could you add some comments or unroll this one-liner?

Comment: @Lokerim, admittedly it's a little dense, but I was able to read it and I didn't write it. In practice, probably better to unroll it for readability with good var names for the intermediate values and that makes it easier (possible, really) to debug if there's a problem.

Comment: Currently this places the entire data on one cell in the excel format is there a way to separate each data in each row

Comment: When you paste the output in excel, use the "Text Import Wizard". Then, select "Delimited". Click "Next". On next screen select "Comma" only and click "finish"