# Syntax - saving a dictionary as a csv file

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I am trying to "clean up" some data - I'm creating a dictionary of the channels that I need to keep and then I've got an `if` block to create a second dictionary with the correct rounding.

Dictionary looks like this:

```
{'time, s': (imported array), 'x temp, C':(imported array),
 'x pressure, kPa': (diff. imported array).....etc}
```

Each imported array is 1-d.

I was looking at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765173/sorting-a-dictionary-and-writing-it-to-a-csv-file?rq=1), but I didn't quite get the way to parse it so that I ended up with what I want.

My desired output is a csv file (do not care if the delimiter is spaces or commas or whatever) with the first row being the keys and the subsequent rows simply being the values.

I feel like what I'm missing is how to use the map function properly.

Also, I'm wondering if I'm using `DictWriter` when I should be using `DictReader`.

This is what I originally tried:

```
with open((filename), 'wb') as outfile:
    write = csv.DictWriter(outfile, Fieldname_order)
    write.writer.writerow(Fieldname_order)
    write.writerows(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DictWriter`'s API doesn't match the data structure you have. `DictWriter` requires list of dictionaries. You have a dictionary of lists.

You can use the ordinary `csv.writer`:

```
my_data = {'time, s': [0,1,2,3], 'x temp, C':[0,10,20,30],
 'x pressure, kPa': [0,100,200,300]}
import csv
with open('outfile.csv', 'w') as outfile:
   writer = csv.writer(outfile)
   writer.writerow(my_data.keys())
   writer.writerows(zip(*my_data.values()))
```

That will write the columns in arbitrary order, which order may change from run to run. One way to make the order to be consistent is to replace the last two lines with:

```
   writer.writerow(sorted(my_data.keys()))
   writer.writerows(zip(*(my_data[k] for k in sorted(my_data.keys()))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: in this example `data` is a list of dictionaries. Each row in the csv contains one value for each key.

To write your dictionary with a header row and then data rows:

```
with open(filename, 'wb') as outfile: 
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(data)
```

To read in data as a dictionary then you do need to use `DictReader`:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(infile)
    data = [row for row in reader]
```

Comment: I do not understand. How am I telling it what dictionary to write FROM?

Comment: Misunderstood. The dictionary you are writing to file is `data` in this case: `writer.writerows(data)`.

Comment: Thanks! Now, I am getting a Value Error on my fieldnames.

Comment: Do you have any guidance as to how to fix my fieldnames? I had a list where I had put them all in order, but it pukes on the first one it uses in the dictionary. It decides that 'Oil Pressure, psi' is really O, i, l,  , P, r, e, s, s, u, r, e, ,,  , p, s, i

Comment: Step back one second: you should be sending a *list* of dictionaries to DictWriter (data should be a list of dictionaries). I see now in your question that you dictionary contains arrays. Instead, you can have a list of dictionaries where each row of data is its own dictionary.

Fieldnames should be a list of fieldnames in the order you want them printed: `['time, s', 'x temp, C', 'x pressure, kPa'...etc]`

Comment: I just realized that it's doing that because there are spaces and commas in the keys. As I change those to _s, it gets stuck on different keys.

Comment: I was wondering why people were having lists of dictionaries...is there a good way to do that?

Comment: If you read from DictReader then you can get a list of dictionaries, which I find more intuitive than a dictionary with lists. However, you can also go with Rob's answer.