# Using dictionary keys as coordinates when writing to csv

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a dictionary which has cell coordinates as the keys and the desired cell content as the value, eg:

```
dict1 = {'AN32': '2', 'AZ17': '47', ect...}
```

The cell range is `D4: AZ52`

I want to write this into a csv file.

The problem I am encountering when it comes to design is that the dictionary isn't necessarily ordered alphabetically or numberically as can be seen in the example above.

I know how to write to a .csv file with

```
with open('example.csv', 'w') as f:

    for i in dict1:

        f.write(str(dict1[i]) + ',')
```

this would write the values out in order, which would mean they wouldn't be in the correct cell, I need them to be in the cell which is specified by their key.

Comment: Possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765173/sorting-a-dictionary-and-writing-it-to-a-csv-file?rq=1

Comment: How is your desired output should look like exactly in the csv file?

Comment: I assume you want the data in the CSV to have 48 columns and 48 rows. Is that correct?

Comment: Correct, 48 columns, 48 rows.

Comment: Can you use an `OrderedDict` (which would store the keys in alphabetical order)?

Comment: It should be pretty easy to create a hard-coded solution that just iterates through the rows and columns of your particular range, but if you want a generic solution that can handle arbitrary ranges, look into enumerating over a range in [the bijective base-26 system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijective_numeration#The_bijective_base-26_system)

Comment: Oops! I made 2 fence-post errors. 'D' to 'AZ' inclusive is actually 49 columns. And `4` to `52` inclusive is 49 rows. Sorry about that.

Comment: @pnuts: It's has to do with how Excel translates rows and column into cell identifiers.

Comment: @pnuts: I know Excel because the OP tagged their question that way. OK, to make you happy, I'll change it to generic "spreadsheet". <sigh>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code uses a list comprehension to build each row.

First we create a list of the column labels, using the `uppercase` string from the `string` module, and we build a list of all the column labels using a simple list comprehension.

Then we use a slightly more complicated list comprehension that makes a key by combining each column label with the current row number (converted to a string). That key is passed to `dict1`'s `.get()` method to get the value associated with that key. We use an empty string `''` as the 2nd arg to `.get()` so that if a key doesn't exist in the dict we get an empty string.

Then we use the `.join()` method to join all those strings, separated by commas.

```
from string import uppercase

#Make a list of the column letters
cols = list(uppercase[3:]) + ['A' + c for c in uppercase]
#print(cols)

with open('example.csv', 'w') as f:
    for r in range(4, 53):
        row = ','.join([dict1.get(c + str(r), '') for c in cols])
        f.write(row + '\n')
```

---

If the values in `dict1` are actually `int` rather than strings, then you need to convert them to strings before attempting to join them. Change the list comprehension to

```
row = ','.join([str(dict1.get(c + str(r), '')) for c in cols])
```

That will cope even if some values are strings and some are numbers.

Comment: I have read and understand the solution, and it is very elegant. However it is also throwing an error: `TypeError: sequence item 12: expected string, into found"`

Comment: @JoeSmart: I suspect that error message actually says "expected string, int found". Are all the values in `dict1` strings? I assumed they were, from your sample data. BTW, I just noticed that you have a key in your sample data of `'Z2'` but you also said that the cell range is `D4: AZ52`.

Comment: My sample data wasn't clear, my apologies. The range I gave is correct. I just typed random coords for the sample data as an example of structure. I'll double check that they're all strings.

Comment: @JoeSmart: Ok. You should fix the `dict1` line in your question. I've updated my answer to handle int values.